# Excel files are not previewed in office web apps

Tags: excel, office-web-apps, office

I have a document library with 10,000 excel files all the files have some macros for calculation in Sharepoint 2013.

When I search on that site collection, sometimes I get a preview, sometimes I don't, it only Says Sorry, an error has occurred and no preview is shown.

It cant be because the files have macros, because some files show previews some others do not.

1. How can I debug this?
2. Anyone experienced a similar issue and fixed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I could notice is that the excel files that are not previewed its because  they have protected sheets, which makes sense!